# How to set margin between controls inside of stack panel without duplication?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I can specify the Margin for each stack panel element, but that will be duplication... and in case of change I will need to update all controls...

Is there any way to define that once for the stack panel?

Thank you

Comment: What's a point to downgrade? Too easy question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sorry for my bad english)

Xin answers is perfect for what you asked but if you want to set more properties for all the stackPanels I suggest you to create a style:

```
 <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="CustomStackPanel">
     <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,12,15,20"/>
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>                
 </Style>
```

and use it like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Background="Red" Style="{StaticResource CustomStackPanel}"/>
    <StackPanel Background="Green" Style="{StaticResource CustomStackPanel}"/>
    <StackPanel Background="Blue" Style="{StaticResource CustomStackPanel}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you remove the `x:Key` from the style, **all** StackPanels inside the element *that contains the style* will use that style. If you declare that style on your `app.xaml`, all stackPanels on your app will use it.